# Pull columns from series of joins in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am kind of stuck at one problem at my job where I need to pull 2 cols from base table and 1 column from a series of joins.

Please note that, I can not provide real data so I am using dummy column/table names and there are 100s of columns in real project.

```
Select A.Name,B.Age, D.Sal 
From A Left join B on A.iD=B.id and B.Date=CURRENT_DATE
(/* join A and B table and return distinct column which is B.XYZ) 
inner join C on C.iD=B.XYZ  
(/* join B and C take C.YYY column for next join */)
inner join D on D.id=C.YYY  
(/* Take out the D.Sal column from this join */) where A.Dept='IT'
```

I have written this query but it is taking forever to run because B.XYZ column has a lot of duplicates. how can I get distinct of B.XYZ column from that join.

Comment: sample data and desired output can help us to help you. We do not need your real data at all,but need to know what kind of data you are working with and what you want to achieve

Comment: Is there a a reason you're opposed to use of whitespace and linebreaks? Your code is, honestly, unreadable.

Comment: Well it's my first question on the portal, not very much familiar with UI. Let me try

Comment: @Larnu if it was hard to write, it should be hard to read ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am using Postgres , now corrected to CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 0):

You say you get the same rows multifold, because for a b.id, date and age you get the same xyz more than once, or so I understand it.

One option is to join with a subquery that gets the distinct data:

```
SELECT a.name, b.age, d.sal 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT id, date, age, xyz FROM b
) dist_b ON dist_b.id = a.id and dist_b.date = CURRENT_DATE
INNER JOIN c ON c.id = dist_b.xyz  
INNER JOIN d ON d.id = c.yyy  
WHERE a.dept = 'IT';
```

Of course you can even move the date condition inside the subquery:

```
SELECT a.name, b.age, d.sal 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT id, age, xyz FROM b WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE
) dist_b ON dist_b.id = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.id = dist_b.xyz  
INNER JOIN d ON d.id = c.yyy  
WHERE a.dept = 'IT';
```

Your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` doesn't work by the way. As you are inner joining the following tables, a match must exists, so your outer join becomes an inner join. For the outer join to work you would have to outer join the following tables, too.

Comment: Select distinct with other cols willl give same dups results

Comment: How can this be? With `DISTINCT` we get each combination of B.id, B.age and B.xyz only once. You need the id to get from A to B and xyz to get from B to C and the age, because you want to select and show it. If you are seeing duplicates, the reason must be somewhere else. Please edit your request and show sample data for the tables and the result you'd be getting with these rows and the result you are expecting instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Joining Table B, you first get a distinct table of the columns you need from B then join.

```
SELECT 
  A.Name,
  B.Age, 
  D.Sal 
From A 
LEFT JOIN ( -- Instead of all cols (*), just id, Date, Age and xyz might do
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM B 
) B ON A.iD = B.id AND B.Date = CURRENT_DATE
    --(/* join A and B table and return distinct column which is B.XYZ */) 
INNER JOIN C ON C.iD = B.XYZ  
    --(/*join B and C take C.YYY column for next join */)
INNER JOIN D ON D.id = C.YYY  
    --(/* Take out the D.Sal column from this join */)
WHERE A.Dept='IT'
```

Comment: Using Select distinct id, Date, Age and xyz give me alot of duplicate , because distinct now look for combination of all cols,

Comment: The challenge here is that you need Date because you are using it for joining to table A and Age because you included it in select. Duplicate of xyz is a data structure issue which cannot be addressed with the limited information that you have shared. It would be more helpful, If you can show enough rows from table B to understand where the problem is.